# vba: Appliation.NormSInv or Application.Worksheetfunction.NormSInv?

Tags: vba

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2007 on Windows 7 Professional, 32 bit version.

I notice that in Excel VBA, Application.Worksheetfunction.NormSInv works, but Application.NormSInv will fail -- cannot find the object.

However, in some books, both appear.

For example, in [Credit Risk Modeling using Excel and VBA Hardcover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470660929) 
by Gunter Löeffler, Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv appears in page 131, 214, etc;  while Application.NormSInv appears in page 125, 128 etc.

Are they the same, or one of it is obsolete (so the code in Gunter's book is a mix)?

For Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv, I found the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835283(v=office.14).aspx); but for Application.NormSInv, I can't find a msdn page in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Application.NormSInv was calling the undocumented function MSOWCFLib.OCFunc.NormSInv in MSOWCF.DLL before Excel 2003. It is quite possible that the author was using an old version of Excel.

see: [The Excel "NORMSINV" Function in Visual Basic](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/9.htm)